# AWS giant data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a linux and windows instance on amazon ec2 for around 7-8 months. Every month i had billing 0.01$ - 0.06$. But two weeks ago i received an abuse report. I looked to my billing and it was of around 20$! 98% of it was DataTransfer. I terminated my instace and changed elastic ip adress. Everything seems good utill today my billing was 31.95! On picture you can see giant month data transfer out beyond the global free tier. It's around 3.5 TB.  [image: Billing details]

Look down for additional info
[image: My configuration]

Was it DDoS? Will IP changing help? Can i setup a data transfer limits?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a third party service, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your direct questions:

- It's impossible to tell if you were under a DDoS attack by looking at those graphs. You would need to have logged the traffic to do some kind of forensics analysis.
- It's hard to tell if changing the IP address will solve your problem without first understanding what the problem is.
- You cannot setup data transfer limits.

I have a few suggestions:

- *Don't*, **never**, ***ever*** open up "administration ports" to 0.0.0.0/0. You are simply asking to be hacked. I see you have SSH open to the world, as well as RDP open to the world. RDP is known for many weaknesses -- I remember a while ago there was a security flaw where anyone could get remote administrator access, or something bad like that. You should add a /32 rule, that is, a rule that allows only your IP address to connect to your instance -- and this only when you actually need to connect to your instance.
- Even though you cannot setup a data transfer limit, ***you can create a Billing alarm***. To create this alarm, you use CloudWatch. There's a Billing metric in which you can define a threshold for an alarm. You can configure the alarm such that whenever the Billing crosses your threshold you get an email notification.

Comment: Good answer.  There is really no way to understand what may have caused the traffic on your servers without understanding exactly what is accessing the servers by looking at server logs and such.